# Dare to think or dare thinking?

Tags: word-choice

In a sentence like this:

> I wouldn't even dare to think about the results.

vs

> I wouldn't even dare thinking about the results.

Are both of them correct? They seem fine on the surface, but when I say it out loud there seems to be something wrong but I don't know (if it's wrong) which part it is wrong.

Comment: They are both correct, assuming nothing in the larger context would render them nonsensical.  I sense that they have slightly different connotations, though I can't think of how to express that difference.

Comment: Which one sounds wrong? Also, what is your reaction to "I wouldn't dare think. . ."?

Answer (score 1):

**Dare** functions as a modal and a lexical verb (it has the same formal properties as *need* when used as a lexical verb - followed with a full form of infinitive for example ***to** think*). So, when used as a modal verb, usually in a negative and interrogative constructions, you would say *I wouldn't even dare think about the results* or *How dare you think about the results?*. However, when used as a lexical verb you would say *I wouldn't even dare to think about the results*. The latter you mentioned - gerund form - is never used with **dare** neither as modal nor as a lexical verb.